# Comapring Decimal with zero in if Statement?

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a decimal field

```
[Display(Name = "DeductedTax")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
public decimal DeductedTax { get; set; }
```

Now in If Statement i want to compare it with zero, actually i want to check that either `Deducted Tax` is zero or null or not

```
        if (payRoll.DeductedTax <= 0)
        {
            if (payRoll.PayRollEmployee.EmployeeSalary.PayGrade == "A+")
            {
                payRoll.DeductedTax = payRoll.EmployeeSalary * 15 / 100;
                payRoll.EmployeeSalary -= payRoll.DeductedTax;
            }
            else if (payRoll.PayRollEmployee.EmployeeSalary.PayGrade == "A")
            {
                payRoll.DeductedTax = payRoll.EmployeeSalary * 10 / 100;
                payRoll.EmployeeSalary -= payRoll.DeductedTax;
            }
            else if (payRoll.PayRollEmployee.EmployeeSalary.PayGrade == "B")
            {
                payRoll.DeductedTax = payRoll.EmployeeSalary * 5 / 100;
                payRoll.EmployeeSalary -= payRoll.DeductedTax;
            }
        }
```

Why i can't compare it with null like null `if (payRoll.DeductedTax <= 0)` and with zero `if (payRoll.DeductedTax <= 0)` ?? and what should i do to get my desired operation done??

Comment: `DeductedTax` can't be null unless you declare it as nullable like `decimal?`

Comment: It can never be `null`. It isn't nullable.

Comment: @simon, soner. then how to check that this decimal value agianst current record exists or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangly this thing worked after cleaning and then building the solutin , i don't know why ,but it did happened

```
if (payRoll.DeductedTax == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare :

```
public decimal? DeductedTax { get; set; }
```

Use:

```
if (payRoll.DeductedTax.HasValue && payRoll.DeductedTax.Value <= 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `decimal DeductedTax` has to be declared as [Nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

```
public decimal ? DeductedTax { get; set; }
```

In that case, it can contain all possible numbers decimal can contain + it can have Null value.

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

`decimal` is a non-nullable type, so even if you could compare it to `null` there would be no point. If the property has not been set, then it will get the default value for a decimal, which is `0` (well, technically it is `0.0M`).

So checking for `0` is effectively checking for both your requirements.

If you require it to allow a null value then you can make it nullable with one of the following ways:

```
public Nullable<decimal> DeductedTax { get; set; }
public decimal? DeductedTax { get; set; }//this is just shorthand for the first
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `decimal?` as a *[nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1t3y8s4s.aspx)*.

```
[Display(Name = "DeductedTax")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
public decimal? DeductedTax { get; set; }
```

With nullable types, value types has their value also they have *additional* `null` value. So after this declaration, you can check them if they are `null` or not.

*Just a tip*: `decimal?` is equavalent to `Nullable<decimal>` .